# How many drawings can a patent have?

Tags: provisional-application, patent-drawings

I'm about to file a USPTO provisional patent in a couple of weeks.

Is there any upper limit for the number of drawings I can have in my utility patent?

Comment: What numbers are you thinking of? I can't find anything, but I'm almost sure there is nothing and you can have as many as you want. I've seen patents with dozens of images, but more than ~10 are normally not needed.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I have around 15 images.

Comment: i dont think that there is upper limit. i can't even find anything as DonQuiKong mentioned. @DonQuiKong Is there any additional fee for extra sheets or each drawing?

Comment: @ASHUVERMA Can you link me to the fee page? I have been told micro entity patent fee is $65 for the first 5 patents

Comment: $65 is the Provisional application filing fee as 37 CFR 1.16(d). i think DonQuiKong can add little more on this.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA I'm not from the US, so I have no experience with those fees. 15 images should be no problem. Maybe Maca knows if there is a limit or explicitly no limit. I haven't heard about a fee for many pages, only for many claims.

Comment: Yeah..Maca can comment on this one. I dont think so there is any limits for drawing. There is fees for extra pages but i m not sure how much for extra pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USPTO imposes an additional fee beyond the provisional filing fee for each 50 sheets beyond 100 sheets (pages) for a provisional patent application.  That fee ranges from $100 for a micro entity, $200 for a small entity and $400 for a large entity. The limit is based on the number of total sheets(pages) in the application, including the drawings and specification.  Other than this additional fee, there is no limitation on the number of drawings.   There is a similar fee structure for when a utility application is filed based on the provisional application.

Other jurisdictions may have other fee structures for the size of the application.

Comment: Come visit the chat, we've got a nice question about us technicalities, but I think I cant tag you if you haven't written in chat ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please refer to [https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule#:~:text=Patent%20Fees,-The%20fees%20subject&text=The%20%24400%2F%24200%20non,in%20paper%20with%20the%20USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule#:%7E:text=Patent%20Fees,-The%20fees%20subject&text=The%20%24400%2F%24200%20non,in%20paper%20with%20the%20USPTO). Please note that this size and fees associated with size keep changing from time to time so check for the latest information. As on September 7th 2020 this information is valid

Comment: I like answers which link to official documentation so bravo. You should perhaps use the linking tool which makes it easier to hide long web addresses.

Comment: HI Eric, you may like only official links but some time official information language is too legal which will not help inventors in better understanding. blogs like our https://invention-patent-drawings.com/patent-drawings-blog/ will try to simplify the information in terms of language and information.

Comment: I find the official links readable. Links to commercial content, especially firms affiliated to the poster, are considered spammy on Stack Exchange and are to be avoided. There are exceptions such as interpretations of court decisions where official guidance isn’t available. Wikipedia articles are usually okay and preferred to commercial blogs.